# Powerbuilder 12.5 - run windows command

Tags: cmd, powerbuilder

I'm working on a Powerbuilder 12.5 program, which is a xml to docx converter. It takes xml files and pictures and stacks them in a folder, which needs to be zip-ed as a .docx file.

I can do that with windows cmd command `zip -r 'path'.docx *`, which generates a word file, which is opened in MS Word. `'path'` is where the user saves the file in file explorer and the name of the file - is dynamicaly generated

How could I run this command from Powerbuilder. The problem is, that if I run the `run()` function it opens the cmd in the preset path, which is c:\Users\ME\

I did try `CD 'new_path && zip -r new_path.docx *`, however it is not working. it zips the c:\Users\ME folder.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set current directory before, just declare SetCurrentDirectoryA in your external functions :

```
FUNCTION LONG SetCurrentDirectoryA(REF STRING curdir) LIBRARY "Kernel32.dll"
```

Comment: Now that I do that, the Run() function opens the windows cmd - however it points to the Oracle\db_home folder. I did try to copy cmd.exe from windows\system32 to the powerbuilder project folder - no luck from that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to windows cmd, however if it is possible in linux terminal, it is possible in windows too.

The finished code looks ike this, using only parsed strings and the run() command

```
ls_exec = "cmd /c cd /d "+ls_folder + " && zip -r "+ ls_folder+".docx * &&   cd /d "+ls_folder_1u   + " && rmdir "+ls_file+" /s /q"
run( ls_exec)
```

It works like a charm. Thank you all for your sugestions.